# Using a larger fuse in my multimeter

Tags: safety, multimeter, fuses

I am trying to replace the burned out fuse in my multimeter. It is very small with dimensions of 3.6mm X 10.25mm and has a rating of 600mA @ 250V.
I can't seem to find this fuse. I can find one with the same dimensions but it has a 1A rating and much larger ones with the same ratings.  Is there any reason why I shouldn't use a larger(physically) fuse in my multimeter? I'd have to make some modifications to the multimeter to accept it of course...(I'd only ever be using this multimeter for low power applications).

[image: the fuse itself]
[image: spot for the fuse]

Comment: You've already blown one fuse which indicates that you are error prone and need protection. Putting a higher rated fuse in is a bad idea. Putting a physically larger fuse in will compromise safety clearance. I'd recommend getting the right fuse.

Comment: The fuse is there to prevent fire. Replace it only with equivalent or faster fuses.

Comment: Do you have an image of the old fuse, or can you provide the markings on it?

Comment: ive added a couple of images. not sure if they'll be of any help. I would say i am reasonably error prone as any beginner is yes but as i stated i wont be working on high voltage projects. i really just wanted to know whether there was any different in the way the fuse operated because if there isnt then it should work in my multimeter after i modify it.

Comment: the blob on the end of the fuse indicates that the fuse wire is soldered in .... just break a 600mA glass fuse and use the fuse wire to replace the blown one .... i have done this before and it works .... otherwiese, install an inline fuse holder, if there is room

Comment: Maybe try something like this and just cut the wire off?  https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/littelfuse-inc/0875.600MXEP/F3287-ND/2059455

Comment: It doesn't matter what voltage level. *That fuse needs to be there to protect the meter circuits, whether you are using it on 1V or 1000V* circuits.

Comment: Thanks fort the replys. Just to straighten this up, if i use a fuse with physically larger dimensions but the same electrical properties, will it work ok? thanks.